# GAE - one-to-one relationship delete giving error

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I am using Eclipse to develop Android with Google App engine. I have 3 entities User->UserDetails->UserPassword. Each one has a @OneToOne relationship to the other thru USER_ID. Following are the entities:

```
@Entity

public class User {

@Id
@Column(name = "USER_ID", allowsNull="false")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Key userId;

@Column(name = "USER_NAME", allowsNull="false")
private String userName;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,optional=false,orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") 
private UserDetails userDetails;
//getters & setters

}



@Entity(name="USER_DETAILS")

public class UserDetails {

@Id
@Column(name = "USER_ID", allowsNull="false")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Key userId;

@Column(name = "USER_FULLNAME", allowsNull="false")
private String userFullname;

@Column(name = "USER_IMAGEURL", allowsNull="false")
private String userImageURL;

@Column(name = "USER_PASSPHRASE", allowsNull="false")
private String userPassPhrase;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") 
private UserPassword userPassword;
//getters & setters
}


@Entity(name = "USER_PASSWORD")

public class UserPassword {

@Id
@Column(name = "USER_ID", allowsNull="false")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Key userId;

@Column(name = "USER_PASSWORD", allowsNull="false")
private String userPassword;
//getters & setters
}
```

I have a `removeAllUsers()` method in `Userendpoint.java`. This method is suppose to get all the users, iterate thru them and remove users, userDetails and passwords one by one.

```
public void removeAllUsers() {

    log.info("UserEndpoint.removeAllUsers().....");
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    User user = new User();
    try {
        CollectionResponse<User> allUsers = listUser(null, null);
        Collection<User> users = allUsers.getItems();
        Iterator<User> itr = users.iterator();

 log.info("UserEndpoint.removeAllUsers()....itr.hasNext="+itr.hasNext());
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            user = itr.next();
            user = mgr.find(User.class, user.getUserId());
            //mgr.getTransaction().begin();
            mgr.remove(user);
            //mgr.getTransaction().commit();

            log.info("UserEndpoint.removeAllUsers()....User removed");
        }

    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    log.info("UserEndpoint.removeAllUsers()....End");
}
```

My assumption is as CascadeType.ALL is used on User, when I delete User, it should remove UserDetails and Password. I also tried with Transaction(lines commented out above). I get the following error:

```
WARNING: Delete of com.bean.User@15a9289 needs delete of related object at com..bean.User.userDetails but cannot delete it direct since FK is here
Jun 12, 2014 12:04:01 PM com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod
INFO: cause={0}
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Illegal argument
at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.NucleusJPAHelper.getJPAExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJPAHelper.java:298)
at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.close(JPAEntityManager.java:197)`enter code here`
at com.cloudmobilebanking.bean.UserEndpoint.removeAllUsers(UserEndpoint.java:202)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Also after some lines I see the below comment also:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cross-group transaction need to be explicitly specified, see TransactionOptions.Builder.withXGfound both Element {
 type: "User"
 id: 0x10780000000000
 }
 and Element {
 type: "User"
 id: 0x12b80000000000
}
```

I have tried using TransactionOptions but get the same error.

I also tried deleting Password then userDetails and then User in that seqyence but still same error.

Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

After working for sometime with JPA/JDO + google endpoints, I gave up (there were multiple issues). JPA/JDO is more for RDBMS but Google datasore is more like a HashMap. I decided to try Objectify which is designed specifically for Google datastore. My experience with it has been better. You need to read the solution below along with the discussion at: [GAE+Objectify - Parameterized type com.googlecode.objectify.Ref not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24590518/gaeobjectify-parameterized-type-com-googlecode-objectify-ref-not-supported/24936550#24936550)
to get a better understanding.

In order to delete the User, UserDetails and Password in Objectify, below is the code.

@ApiMethod(name = "deleteAllUsers", path="delete_all_users")

```
public void deletAllUsers(){
    log.info("UserEndpoint.deletAllUsers...");
    List<User> users =  ofy().load().type(User.class).list();
    User user = null;
    try{
        for(int i=0; i< users.size(); i++){
            user = users.get(i);
            UserDetails userDetails = user.getUserDetails();
            UserPassword userPassword = user.getUserPassword();
            ofy().delete().entity(userDetails).now();
            ofy().delete().entity(userPassword).now();
            ofy().delete().entity(user).now(); 
        }
    }

    catch(Exception e){
        log.info("AccountEndpoint.deleteAllUsers()...exception="+e.getMessage());
    }
    log.info("AccountEndpoint.deletAllUsers...all users deleted");
}
```